# Restricted Access Using Scope in JWT and Spring

Tags: spring, jwt

Well, i have a JWT with scope definied in a claim called **scp**, see the peace of jwt:

```
  "scp": "xpto_role user_impersonation",
```

So, in my Spring application i have the following Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/urlabc/**").hasAuthority("abc")
                .antMatchers("/urlabc/**").authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("xpto");
    }
}
```

ANd in my restController:

```
@RestController
public class TestResourceOne {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint001")
    public Double endpoint001(@RequestParam("value") Double value) {
        return Math.sqrt(value);
    }

}
```

Look, my scope passed by JWT is "xpto_role" in claim **scp**. In my SpringApp i want to force a Access Denied so i putted a "abc" role in "hasAuthority" method, but user is allowed to access my endpoint anyway.

The configuration is correct ?

**Edit 1:**
After remove the "authenticated()" line and putted the correct role i got Access Denied yet, see the error:

```
2018-07-20 16:57:36.732 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /calcsqrt?value=10.0 at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-07-20 16:57:36.732 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@8f785707: Principal: null; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Not granted any authorities'
2018-07-20 16:57:36.732 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /calcsqrt?value=10.0 at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-07-20 16:57:36.732 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@63dfada0
2018-07-20 16:57:36.732 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /calcsqrt?value=10.0 at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-07-20 16:57:36.733 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /calcsqrt?value=10.0 at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-07-20 16:57:36.733 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/calcsqrt'; against '/calcsqrt/**'
2018-07-20 16:57:36.733 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /calcsqrt?value=10.0; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(hasRole('ROLE_EXEC_CALCSQRT'))]
2018-07-20 16:57:36.733 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@8f785707: Principal: null; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Not granted any authorities
2018-07-20 16:57:36.733 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@7475b738, returned: -1
2018-07-20 16:57:36.734 DEBUG 6828 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
```

Comment: you're allowing authenicated users to the same endpoint, to have a role you will be authenticated.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand your point. Can you explain better with example or a article explain it ?

Comment: remove `.antMatchers("/urlabc/**").authenticated();`. You are checking for a role on the same endpoint, this will superseed that check it is less granular. To have a role defined you will be authenticated.

Comment: I removed and now i got "Access Denied" as expected. But putting the correct ".hasAuthority("xpto_role"); i got "Access Denied" yet and in this case is wrong because role is correct.

Comment: are you 100% sure you the authories are setup? You could set the logging levels for security and web, `org.springframework.security=debug`, `org.springframework.web=debug` it will print out the authencation object w/ the roles/authorities/details/principal etc.

Comment: I edited my post with the log returned.

Comment: `Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@8f785707: Principal: null; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Not granted any authorities` You need to validate your JWT, decrypt it with something like JOSE, and parse the claims to authroties. Currently you can _only_ grant `authenticated` access

Comment: Well, my JWT is already validated and my claims too. i.e: If the jwt is expired the Spring return "token expired" as expected. But only aurhorities didn't work. Do you have any link to help me ?

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt has a walkthough, you need to parse your JWT for Spring, it cannot do it for you for custom claims

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176445/discussion-between-ronaldolanhellas-and-darren-forsythe).